# Help Identify Potential BLDC Protection Circuit

Tags: power-supply, brushless-dc-motor, protection

I am trying to determine the function of a small circuit on a separate PCB that feeds a more complex Brushless DC Motor PCB. As far as I can tell (from physically measuring between 9V-24V) the output voltage equals the input voltage.

I'm trying to understand why I couldn't just bypass this circuit and directly connect a voltage source. Is this some kind of protection circuit?

The two unidentified capacitors are ceramic SMDs about 1.5mm x 3mm.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing this circuit does is protect against reverse polarity from an improperly-connected battery.

The inductor and capacitors provide noise suppression.

The reverse-polarity protection is a trick I first saw described by Bob Pease {National Semiconductor}.

If you look at the current flow through the MOSFET while the battery is connected properly, you will see that the reverse-connected diode inside the MOSFET is forward-biased. That would normally result in a voltage drop of about 0.6 Vdc. However, the Gate has a positive voltage with respect to the Source. The MOSFET is thus fully-enhanced, resulting in a very-low voltage drop.

If the battery is reverse-connrcted, the internal diode is reverse-biased and the Gate is also reverse-biased. The MOSFET does not conduct and thus protects the rest of the system.

Comment: I realized that if this auxiliary circuit is directly connected to the motor it works fine, but if I wire it about a foot from the motor it won't work. It just clicks. I'm not sure why.